# Any free cloud server available for couchdb installation?

Tags: server, cloud, couchdb

Guys I want to use couchdb as a backend for my own app. Upto 3 user app only. For this usecase I need free cloud server with couchdb installation support. Any free cloud server available now?

Comment: Cloudant offer a free tier with a storage limit of 1gb

Comment: This question is off-topic here. StackOverflow does not permit questions seeking off-site resources.

Answer (score -2):

Many cloud providers offer a free tier and a web search for "free tier cloud server" returns too many results to list here. The servers run an operating system and it is this that needs support for couchdb not the cloud provider.

You can [install couchdb](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/install/unix.html) directly on of the following operating systems:

- CentOS/RHEL 7
- CentOS/RHEL 8
- Debian 9 (stretch)
- Debian 10 (buster)
- Ubuntu 16.04 (xenial)
- Ubuntu 18.04 (bionic)
- Ubuntu 20.04 (focal)

Or you can try a [docker container](https://hub.docker.com/_/couchdb).